# JavaScript: My for loop seems to be not working when I am trying to work with DOM

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, dom

The thing is, the problem seems to be coming from the for loop itself. When I delete the code inside it and put `alert(c);`, for example, it's not doing anything. I used the same method earlier for just a little bit different thing and it's working perfectly. Here's what I did with my earlier problem:

```
for (var b = 0; b <= 99; b++) {
    var boxTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".icon2.windowbg[style]")[b];
    boxTwo.style.backgroundColor = "#552222";
}
```

It works completely fine. Unfortunately, I can't say the same thing about my new problem:

```
for (var c = 0; c <= 99; c++) {
    var boxOneNew = document.querySelectorAll(".icon1.windowbg.topicnew")[c];
    boxOneNew.style.backgroundColor = "#552222";
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".icon1.windowbg.topicnew")` does it return anything at all? Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: please share your HTML. It seems likely that your selector isn't picking up 100 different elements, as it needs to for this code to not throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the boxTwo out of your loop, and loop condition should be boxTwo.length to prevent from error `style of null` unless your `boxTwo` length is `98`.

```
var boxTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".icon2.windowbg[style]");
for (var b = 0; b < boxTwo.length; b++) {
  boxTwo[b].style.backgroundColor = "#552222";
}
```

Do it for your second code as well:

```
var boxOneNew = document.querySelectorAll(".icon1.windowbg.topicnew");
for (var c = 0; c < boxOneNew.length; c++) {
  boxOneNew[c].style.backgroundColor = "#552222";
}
```

**Note:** make sure that `.icon1.windowbg.topicnew` match something in the DOM.

Comment: Is that supposed to work with the second code as well? As I said, the first one has no problems. But its method doesn't seem to work with the second one. Nevermind, you edited your comment.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted,

```
<td class="icon1 windowbg topicnew">...</td>
```

The other part of the code is pretty much the same thing, it just doesn't have the `'topicnew'` class. What I am trying to do is change this element's background color.
And yes, there are 99 elements.